# Identity Server 4 with multiple user stores

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core, identity, identityserver4, .net-framework-version

I just started working on integrating Identity Server 4. I am looking for some solution to have three distinct user stores for three different applications/Clients.
Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have access to the ID of the current client on the login page - so yes absolutely.

Check the quickstart UI

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI

Comment: So, you mean In 'IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator' validateAsync method  
public Task ValidateAsync(ResourceOwnerPasswordValidationContext context)
        {
            if (context.Request.Client.ClientId == "Client1")
            {
                // Validate from store 1
            }
            else if (context.Request.Client.ClientId == "Client1")
            {
                //ValidateAsync from 2nd store
            }
            else
            {
                //validate from 3rd store
            }
        }
i can do like this?